# Recharts PieChart - Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I found many similarly titled questions, but none of them addresses how to resolve 'Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop' in case of Recharts PieChart.

Can someone tell - in which part of the code I should add keys?

I tried adding it in  section as

```
<Pie key={index} />
```

I tried adding key in different other parts.

It did not help.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding key in different parts, but

error got resolved only when I added 'key={index}' in 'data.map((entry, index)' part as follows:

```
 data.map((entry, index) => <Cell key={index} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />)
```

Hope it helps someone !

Comment: but it might break if you attempt something similar to this again